# tkMessageBox

Tags: python, tkmessagebox

Can anybody help me out in how to activate 'close' button of askquestion() of tkMessageBox??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By 'activate', do you mean make it so the user can close the message box by clicking the close ('X') button?

I do not think it is possible using `tkMessageBox`. I guess your best bet is to implement a dialog box with this functionality yourself.

BTW: What should `askquestion()` return when the user closes the dialog box?

Comment: i dont need a retun type when it closes...
when i push "yes" it returns yes.Similarly for "No"

Comment: So you want it to return None on close. AFAIK, it cannot be done with tkMessageBox. Implement your own dialog box class/functions. See http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm . The tkSimpleDialog module is part of the standard python distro. Inherit that, see the example under 'Creating a simple dialog, revisited', where the apply() method sets a return value.

Comment: How to write text on a frame while creating dialog boxes using Tkinter ?

Comment: I suggest you add a label widget to the dialog box.